# Agregar nueva fila a QTableWidget y que su QComboBox tenga el mismo item seleccionado que el QComboBox de la fila anterior

Tags: python, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica

He creado una función **'mas'** que me permite agregar filas nuevas en una tabla en caso de darle clic a su respectivo botón (ver giff más abajo).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QComboBox, 
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class subwindowDatosEntrada_Dinamic(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(subwindowDatosEntrada_Dinamic,self).__init__(parent)
        self.btn_mas.clicked.connect(self.mas)

    def mas(self): 
        nuevo = self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount()  
        self.table_datosEntrada.insertRow(nuevo)

        for row in range(self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount() - 1, self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount(), 1):
            for rowe in range(self.table_datosEntrada.columnCount()):

                # AQUÍ DEFINO LOS COMBO's BOX's CORRESPONDIENTES DE MI TABLA Y LOS CENTRO --------------------------- 
                c2 = QComboBox()
                c2.addItems(['HEA', 'HEB', 'IPE'])
                c2.setEditable(True) # Pasos para centrarComboBox
                c2.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
                c2.lineEdit().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                for i in range(c1.count()):
                    c2.setItemData(i, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
#                    c2.setCurrentIndex(i-1)
```

Busco que al crear nuevas filas, mi ítem del combo box se actualice con la selección que hice en la fila anterior **(el giff ilustra mejor el objetivo)**

Se que se lo podría realizar con el método *setCurrentIndex*, pero no consigo nada.

Existe alguna solución que pueda servir para este problema? Saludos cordiales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Si se fijan, al hacer clic en el botón '+', las filas que se generan ya se quedan con la selección anterior del ComboBox, eso es precisamente lo que busco.

Existe alguna solución que pueda servir para este problema? Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente puedes asignar el índice con el método `QComboBox.setCurrentIndex`, pero previamente debes usar `QTableWidget.cellWidget` para obtener un referencia al widget de la anterior fila y luego `QComboBox.currentIndex` para obtener su índice.

Te dejo un ejemplo completo reproducible:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("self")
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.table_datosEntrada = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.table_datosEntrada.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 31, 621, 461))
        self.table_datosEntrada.setObjectName("table_datosEntrada")
        self.table_datosEntrada.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table_datosEntrada.setRowCount(0)
        self.mas()
        self.btn_mas = QtWidgets.QPushButton("+", self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_mas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 30, 88, 34))
        self.btn_mas.clicked.connect(self.mas)
        self.btn_menos = QtWidgets.QPushButton("-", self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_menos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 70, 88, 34))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()


    def mas(self):
        indice_fila = self.table_datosEntrada.rowCount()
        self.table_datosEntrada.insertRow(indice_fila)

        for indice_col in range(2):
            combo_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            combo_box.addItems(['HEA', 'HEB', 'IPE'])
            combo_box.setEditable(True)
            combo_box.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
            combo_box.lineEdit().setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            for i in range(combo_box.count()):
                combo_box.setItemData(i, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)

            self.table_datosEntrada.setCellWidget(
                indice_fila, indice_col, combo_box
                )

            if indice_fila != 0:
                last_index = self.table_datosEntrada.cellWidget(
                    indice_fila - 1, indice_col
                    ).currentIndex()
                combo_box.setCurrentIndex(last_index)

            indice_col += 1
            item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            if indice_fila != 0:
                value = self.table_datosEntrada.item(
                    indice_fila - 1, indice_col
                    ).text()
            else:
                value = 0
            item.setData(Qt.EditRole, value)
            self.table_datosEntrada.setItem(indice_fila, indice_col, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]